# Are Pthreads handled the same way on old ARM Linux?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I am developing a software that will run on an embedded ARM Linux. It uses Posix threads and runs great when compiled for my computer. But as soon as I cross-compile it I see strange thread issues:

1. Detached threads and joined threads do not exit when they return. I can still see them in the processes list. They only go away when the main thread exits.
2. Signals are handled in a strange way. I know that signals can be tricky with threads so I block them all and only allow them in a thread that handles them properly. However on my ARM box this thread is not able to catch any signal.

The system in this ARM box is quite outdated, it uses Linux 2.6.9 and my toolchain is GCC 3.3.2. Is anyone aware of some kind of limitations of Posix threads on such system?

---

Here is some of my code that handles signals:

```
/**
*   Thread that just waits for signals to catch
*/
static void *signals(void *arg) {

    sigset_t *set = (sigset_t *) arg;
    int sig;

    if (pthread_sigmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, set, NULL))
        warnx("Cannot unblock signals");

    while (program_should_continue()) {

        /* wait for a signal */
        if (sigwait(set, &sig))
            warnx("Could not handle signal");

        switch (sig) {

            /* Do stuff */
        }
    }

    return NULL;

}
```

Creation of the threads:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    /* set the signals to be bocked for threads */
    sigemptyset(&sigset);
    sigaddset(&sigset, SIGQUIT);
    sigaddset(&sigset, SIGTERM);
    sigaddset(&sigset, SIGINT);
    sigaddset(&sigset, SIGALRM);
    if (pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, &sigset, NULL))
        errx(EXIT_FAILURE, "Cannot block signals for new threads");

    /* set attributes for detached threads */
    pthread_attr_init(&detached_attr);
    pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&detached_attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);

    /* create signal thread */
    if (pthread_create(&pth_signals, &detached_attr, signals, (void*) &sigset)) {
        errx(EXIT_FAILURE, "Cannot create thread signals");
    } else {
        if (pthread_setname(pth_signals, "signals"))
            warnx("Cannot set thread name");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only thing I can imagine is that on very old systems [LinuxThreads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LinuxThreads) were used instead of NPTL which is the current implementation of pthreads on Linux. LinuxThreads has a number of problems, in particular relating to signal handling. From the [LinuxThreads FAQ](http://pauillac.inria.fr/~xleroy/linuxthreads/faq.html),

> If the signal is sent via kill() or the tty interface (e.g. by pressing ctrl-C), then the POSIX specs say that the handler is executed by any thread in the process that does not currently block the signal. In other terms, POSIX considers that the signal is sent to the process (the collection of all threads) as a whole, and any thread that is not blocking this signal can then handle it.
>
> The latter case is where LinuxThreads departs from the POSIX specs. In LinuxThreads, there is no real notion of ``the process as a whole'': in the kernel, each thread is really a distinct process with a distinct PID, and signals sent to the PID of a thread can only be handled by that thread. As long as no thread is blocking the signal, the behavior conforms to the standard: one (unspecified) thread of the program handles the signal. But if the thread to which PID the signal is sent blocks the signal, and some other thread does not block the signal, then LinuxThreads will simply queue in that thread and execute the handler only when that thread unblocks the signal, instead of executing the handler immediately in the other thread that does not block the signal.
>
> This is to be viewed as a LinuxThreads bug, but I currently don't see any way to implement the POSIX behavior without kernel support.

Comment: You are right. When I execute `/lib/libc.so.6` it tells me that it uses LinuxThreads. I should have thought about it before. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You have the old [LinuxThreads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LinuxThreads) implementation rather than the newer NPTL implementation. Signals are totally mishandled under PosixThreads -- each thread has its own PID and behaves like a process.